# Move an image following vector image path

Tags: android

I'm developping an Android app ,for cars accidents the aim is to indicate where the accident happen in the car using an arrow and car picture like this[image]

My current problem is how to let the user move the red arrow using his phone allong the car image without letting the red arrow enter inside the car , in other word , the red arrow will follow the outside path line of the car.

So how can we do this ?

Comment: It is unclear if at the moment you can let the user move the arrow already. Please elaborate. And how is the direction of the arrow adjusted?

Comment: the arrow is just a picture , the user need to show the him the impact point , or where the car has been hit. so the user tap on the arrow and move his finger ,and the arrow must stick to the car outside line.

Comment: You did not answer both of my questions. Please reread. I like to help you but if we do not understand each other...

Comment: the direction is like the picture , you see , and the user just hold the arrow and try to move it.

Comment: You did not answer my first comment.

Comment: i'm really confused ! what didn't you missunderstand , what i want to do is to be able to move the red arrow that all, but moving it only on the outside shape of the car not inside , , the problem is to limit the movement of the arrow on outside the cars not inside

Comment: My god i already know for five hours what you want. But you were not able to answer a simple remark during the last four hours. Read! Read! You did not elaborate.

Comment: The arrow direction is the same , just to move it from a place to another on the car lines , the arrow is not problem how to move a picture follwing the path of the car that all !!!

Comment: You again told the same. I know that already eleven hours now. Repeat, you should answer on this: `It is unclear if at the moment you can let the user move the arrow already. `.

Comment: yes the user move the arrow , is it clear now ! why this is so important to you !  is there any solution now

Comment: `yes the user move the arrow `. Sorry but that is no answer to my question. If you cannot answer even my simple question then how would it go if i am going to explain to you how you can solve it. Of course there is a solution. But show please that we are able to communicate.

Comment: Ok , what i'm trying to do is to detect the shape edges of the car and move my arrow along the edge of the car. at the begining the arrow is placed in default place sticked to the car shape, and the user after that can move the arrow along the edge of the car . is it cear enough now ?

Comment: It was yesterday already clear enough. I said that five times already. You keep repeating yourself. But i wait for a decent answer on my question. If we cannot communicate then it makes little sense to talk about a solution for your problem.

Comment: I don't understand ! what did you missunderstand ?

Comment: It is unclear if at the moment you can let the user move the arrow already. i answered YES ,                                                                                       Please elaborate. And how is the direction of the arrow adjusted? The arrow direction is like what you see in the picture . I What did i miss  ?

Comment: Please i'm running out of time , if you have an idea a tutorial please tell me !

Comment: `i answered YES ` ? No. You answered `yes the user move the arrow`. Which is, if that even is correct english, a multi interpretable answer. And now you repeated three questions where i only clearly asked for an answer on my first question. Conclusion: we cannot communicate.

Comment: Ok thank you anyway !

Comment: The arrow direction will go to the center of the car images whenever the user move the arrow it will stick to the car's border and always direct to the center of the car's image

Comment: Is this what you want? Or did you succeed programming it this way? If you succeeded then please tell how.

Comment: Yes this is what i want , i'm still thinking of a solution , but i'm still stuck !

Comment: So this started again with a difficult communication ;-).

Comment: Question: if the car was a rectangle then would you be able to determine if the user clicked, or moverd the arrow, ouside the car or inside the car?

Comment: you are really hard to talk with  , i will answer your question right away ! i've told you YES this is what i want , i did not succeed to find out a solution . is it clear now ?

Comment: Yes it's possible with the rectangle coordinates and distance

Comment: Ok. Then if you draw a rectangle around the car you are done. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: but the shape of the car is not like a rectangle ? how to deal with that ,

Comment: I know that a car is not a rectangle. But you are again not answering my question to the pont! How hard is it to communicate! Draw a rectangle in which the car fits. Then use the rectangle as car. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: `you are really hard to talk with ` Please remove that comment. You expose yourself too much in this way.

Comment: Ok @greenapps thank you for your help !

Comment: My god... im in... i offer you help... dont run away! Dont you see i know how to do it?

Comment: i'm still here , i've just thanked you for your help :)

Comment: Still the problem of the direction of the arrow ?

Comment: ANSWER MY QUESTION!

Comment: WHAT QUESTION ?

Comment: `Conclusion: we cannot communicate.`

Comment: Yes we cannot communicate , because it's not easy to talk with you . you are so hard to talk with  , this is true ! if you want to help me , you won't act like this !

Comment: Even when i thank you is a problem with you .